# Google Cloud Pub/Sub Publishing from Browser - How does Auth work?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I have a requirement to use Google Cloud Pub/Sub API directly from Browser ( similar to GA script). I was wondering how can in handle Auth without requiring going through a back-end server.

I want to invoke the Cloud Pub/Sub API directly from the browser. I tried and it says i need to authenticate first , my issue is how to secure the Auth Token.

Is there any javascript library that is available which i can use in Browser ( not backend) to invoke the Google Pub/Sub API.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @sathishsenathi, any chance you can share the javascript code used in the browser to access pub/sub if you still have it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general approach in Javascript for authorizing and making authorized requests to Google APIs is shown at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#AuthorizingandMakingAuthorizedRequests -- it's not specific to the Cloud Pubsub API, but it should work for *all* Google APIs.  Similarly, https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js for general Javascript access to Google APIs.

Comment: Is there an example/sample anywhere of someone actually using javascript in a browser to subscribe to a Google pubsub channel?

Comment: As far as I can see, the example from the first link describes how to authenticate a user and then perform requests on behalf of that user. *"It's called "authorized" access because the user must give the application direct authorization to use personal data. "*. So I think this is not what OP is looking for. As far as I can tell, you need to bounce the push to Pub/Sub via some proxy server. So a backend is required. There are however lean solutions such as Google Cloud Functions to get a managed endpoint easily.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old topic, but I've been recently assessing if it's possible. The simple answer is - yes, it is possible to send messages into PubSub topics directly from a browser application. The solution is as follows:

- You need to post a message via REST API using *fetch()*
- You need to send the **Authorization** header
- **Authorization** header has to contain oAuth2.0 token identifying the user; it can be an anonymous authenticated user or fully authenticated, using firebase authentication library for example.

To have all three above working perfectly, you'd have to write a **lot** of code. It is not practical at all and architecturally not nice. Unless you absolutely need to do it that way, not another (I can't see why though), the simplified but involving a bit more components solution is as follows:

- **Authenticate** user in-browser via firebase - can be either anonymous or full user
- Do simple **GET** or **POST** to your cloud/firebase **function** with the required payload
- In function **validate** the incoming request which will have authenticated user token
- If validation is good then **publish message** into the topic

This way it's still secure, much more maintainable and clearly separated into functional components. **Less** code, a bit more infrastructure.